# Sort Connected Components from Right to Left

Tags: matlab, sorting, connected-components

How can I sort connected components from right to left and bottom to top in MATLAB? For example, I have this in the resulting label matrix `L`:

```
L = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 4 4 0 0 0; ...
     0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 4 4 4 0 0; ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5; ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5];
```

I want the connected components in an image to be read from right to left and get this in `L` instead:

```
L = [0 0 0 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 2 2 0 0 0; ...
     0 0 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 2 2 2 0 0; ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1; ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1];
```

I have used the `regionprops` function in MATLAB but it seems to work from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Labeling (such as that done by [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html)) appears to follow a linear ordering, meaning it goes *down* each column from left to right, labeling regions in the order it first finds them.

If you want to instead label each region from right to left, but still *down* each column, you can [flip](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) your matrix from left to right first, do the labeling, then flip the result back again. For example:

```
L = flip(bwlabel(flip(bw, 2), 4), 2);
```

If you want to label each region from right to left, but instead go *up* each column, you can use 180 degree [rotations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html) of your matrix instead of flipping it:

```
L = rot90(bwlabel(rot90(bw, 2), 4), 2);
```

Another option that will simply reverse the labels in `L` is as follows:

```
L(L > 0) = max(L(:))+1-L(L > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It seems to be working perfectly with the L = rot90(bwlabel(rot90(bw, 2), 4), 2); command. and is reading labels from right to left and bottom up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rotate the binary image?

```
%bin_img is the binary image
bin_img = rot90(rot90(bin_img));

%use regionprops like you want
%after this, you can retunr the image to the original

bin_img = rot90(rot90(bin_img));
```